# show posts found in multiple categories via category_name query string?

Tags: categories, query

I am attempting to allow visitors to filter posts in an archive to show posts that are found in two categories. The code is building the URL as follows:

domain/?category_name=slug1+slug2

Previously, this seemed to work properly, but now it will only load the archive for category of slug1. I can't find anything in the Codex that indicates that the WP protocol has changed for this query string. Any ideas if this has changed of if there is a better way to trigger this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be not your case but if behind the scene permalink settings have been switched from default one, then the request:

*?category_name=slug1+slug2*

is rewritten to

*/category/slug1/* or */category/slug2/*

so only the posts from one category are shown.